# How to access an HTML checkbox value using Java in a JSP file?

Tags: java, html, jsp

So I have a checkbox method:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedFees" value="$185">Hotel Accommodation (Conference Guest Special Fee - Parking Included)<br>
```

So in my JSP file, in  order to extract the value, I did

```
String[] selectedFees = request.getParameterValues("selectedFees");
```

And I get `["$185"]`.

However, I also want to get the string `Hotel Accommodation (Conference Guest ...` string.

I was wondering if this is even possible or what other method can I use to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That String doesnt change....right? maybe you could just include it in the form as a hidden field. so you can just use the same syntax to get it `String myString = request.getparameter("myString");`

Answer (score 0):

That display text does not get sent in the http request. If you want that value you can use a hidden input and get it from that parameter. And if you need to toggle what display text gets sent in the hidden input, then use Javascript.

**Example**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkBoxDisplay" value="Hotel Accommodation (Conference Guest ..." />
```

Then in the JSP:

```
String checkBoxDisplay = request.getParameter("checkBoxDisplay");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also include the string in the value as well with a separate char, but you need to parse it later

`<input type="checkbox" name="selectedFees" value="$185|Hotel Accommodation (Conference Guest Special Fee - Parking Included)">Hotel Accommodation (Conference Guest Special Fee - Parking Included)`